# Calculate Points Allocated Based on Position and Golf Score

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

We are adding the players and their golf scores manually but would like to automatically calculate the **Points** column. I can do this easily if there was never a tie based on the score. The question is, how can I formulaically calculate the points in case of a tie?

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SmqGTsIjb_Nksvfva0O_Rzvu5rWIto-pLZJl9ZbTTe8/edit?usp=sharing)

**This below would work for the Points column formula if you never had a tie**

```
=IF(G3=1,12,IF(G3=2,11,IF(G3=3,10,IF(G3=4,9,IF(G3=5,8,IF(G3=6,7,IF(G3=7,6,IF(G3=8,5,IF(G3=9,4,IF(G3=10,3,IF(G3=11,2,IF(G3=12,1))))))))))))
```

| Place | Player | Score | Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lisa | 45 | 12 |
| 2 | Gerrard | 46 | 11 |
| 3 | Hans | 47 | 10 |
| 4 | Zimmer | 48 | 9 |
| 5 | Wheeler | 49 | 8 |
| 6 | Walker | 50 | 7 |
| 7 | Junior | 51 | 6 |
| 8 | Till | 52 | 5 |
| 9 | Lindemann | 53 | 4 |
| 10 | David | 54 | 3 |
| 11 | Bowie | 55 | 2 |
| 12 | Lars | 56 | 1 |

**This below runs a basic comparison above and below to detect a tie, but isn't smart enough to calculate the points**

```
=IF(AND(C18<>C17,C18<>C19),IF(A18=1,12,IF(A18=2,11,IF(A18=3,10,IF(A18=4,9,IF(A18=5,8,IF(A18=6,7,IF(A18=7,6,IF(A18=8,5,IF(A8=9,4,IF(A18=10,3,IF(A18=11,2,IF(A18=12,1)))))))))))),"TIE")
```

| **Place** | **Player** | **Score** | **Points** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lisa | 45 | 12 |
| 2 | Gerrard | 46 | 11 |
| 3 | Hans | 47 | 10 |
| 4 | Zimmer | 49 | **TIE** |
| 5 | Wheeler | 49 | **TIE** |
| 6 | Walker | 51 | 7 |
| 7 | Junior | 53 | **TIE** |
| 8 | Till | 53 | **TIE** |
| 9 | Lindemann | 53 | **TIE** |
| 10 | David | 56 | 3 |
| 11 | Bowie | 59 | 2 |
| 12 | Lars | 60 | 1 |

**If your point allocation looked like the following, your points in case of a tie are just the average of all the complementary score point allocations**

| **Place** | **Points** |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 11 |
| 3 | 10 |
| 4 | 9 |
| 5 | 8 |
| 6 | 7 |
| 7 | 6 |
| 8 | 5 |
| 9 | 4 |
| 10 | 3 |
| 11 | 2 |
| 12 | 1 |

Comment: Did you read the tags?  Both google-sheets and excel both state that you should not use these together.  Please choose the one that you are actually using and remove the tag of the other.

Comment: @ScottCraner So if I'm open to using either Sheets OR Excel, should I cross-post to both tags? I don't have a preferred platform for this problem.

Comment: It is considered too broad to do either/or.

Comment: @ScottCraner OK, I will make a separate post for Excel

Comment: Instead, here is a formula that will work in Excel.  With your third table in `F1:G13` to use as the lookup: `=AVERAGE(INDEX($G$2:$G$13,MATCH(COUNTIF($C$2:$C$13,"<"&C2)+1,$F$2:$F$13,0)):INDEX($G$2:$G$13,MATCH(COUNTIF($C$2:$C$13,"<"&C2)+COUNTIF($C$2:$C$13,C2),$F$2:$F$13,0)))`  The caveat is that the lookup table(your third table above in `F1:G13` must be in sorted descending order as you are showing.

Comment: Thanks Scott, that works like a champ so far. Can you please post as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Sorry  the lookup column, the Place column must be sorted ASCENDING not descending.

Comment: Well, now that it is google-sheets centric per the rules, that formula will not work in google sheets.  There are a lot of formula in google-sheets that are not available in Excel.  My hope was that those that know google-sheets would come up with a better formula than I.

Comment: Well the exact same formula works great in both Excel and Sheets, so I can build this out in either now. Thank you. Please post as the answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your data Lookup table in F1:G13 we can use INDEX(MATCH()) and COUNTIFS to set the extents of a range:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX($G$2:$G$13,MATCH(COUNTIF($C$2:$C$13,"<"&C2)+1,$F$2:$F$13,0)):INDEX($G$2:$G$13,MATCH(COUNTIF($C$2:$C$13,"<"&C2)+COUNTIF($C$2:$C$13,C2),$F$2:$F$13,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Scott-Craner, this works great. Tested in both Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel (v365)